# Improving contrast between dot and paper in dot blot

Tags: biochemistry, antibody, protocol, assay-development

Currently using dot blot to attempt to determine if a serum contains antibodies for some reagents I am testing.

- I pipetted samples as 10-5ul dots on whatman paper.
- Incubation steps were for 1 hour with light shaking.
- Blocking solution is composed of 1mg/ml BSA in PBS.
- Wash steps were 3X PBS for 10 minute each.
- Solution for incubating the blot in primary antibody was 1ml of serum per 9ml of blocking solution.
- Solution for incubating the blot in secondary antibody was 100ul of IgG in 10ml of blocking solution.
- Then a 1:10 DAB substrate mix was used to develop the blot. Products used for the test listed below.

Currently, the whatman paper is a light brown with vague outlines of the dots where the samples were pipetted. Samples that should trigger more antibodies than others (like serum positive control) tend to be a bit darker, but it's not nearly as clear as we'd hope for.

I have also blotted the IgG which usually forms a darker smudge, rather than a clean, dark dot. Does anyone have any advice on how to improve the developing process? I have also tried using TBS, adding Tween to the PBS or TBS as well as trying nitrocellulose instead, but none of these have impacted the results.
Reagents:

- [secondary antibody](https://www.thermofisher.com/antibody/product/Goat-anti-Human-IgG-H-L-Secondary-Antibody-Polyclonal/31410)
- [DAB kit](https://www.thermofisher.com/order/catalog/product/34002)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In the absence of another answer, I'll transition my comments to an answer.

1. Please label your images.
2. Both an [Abcam guide](https://www.abcam.com/kits/dab-staining) and a [Thermo troubleshooting document](https://www.thermofisher.com/us/en/home/life-science/protein-biology/protein-biology-learning-center/protein-biology-resource-library/pierce-protein-methods/ihc-troubleshooting-guide.html) suggest using a kit or DAB protocol including metals such as nickel or cobalt to intensify signal. I notice that the kit spec that you link doesn't seem to have these. Have you tried different DAB kits?
3. They also recommend carefully monitoring staining over time under a scope and removing as early as possible. This may help to reduce background.
4. I'd try a few different combinations of conditions, stain + wash times, to see if any have an effect. I don't have a great sense of where your protocol came from, I'd suggest clicking through those documents above or searching the literature to find more DAB protocols that you might try.